# What is the keyboard shortcut for google chrome's focus mode?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to be able to focus on the content of website without the distractions from the address bar, bookmarks, extensions, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

For macs:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

For others:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**, the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>F11</kbd>. You can also do it from the google Chrome settings.

[image: full screen mode in google chrome]